# error with try-except method in python

Tags: python, try-catch

I am having a problem with the try-except method i would like to monitor any errors in my script by sending those errors to my mail the script only checks file existence and it looks like:

```
def check_file_existence():
     try:
       with open('\\\\ntsrv1\\tohna\\SecurityTeam\\Varonis\\Varonis_monitoring_report\\Varonis_Action_Report.csv', 'r') as temp_file:
           temp_file.close()
     except ValueError as e:
         e = str(e)
         print(e)
         status_mail_notofication('error in move_report_to_folder_adding_date_to_file Function under varonis_report_analysis script  ','there was an error in check_file_existence Function','security88876@gmail.com')
         sys.exit(0)
     return
```

after running the code with purpose to get an error

i am getting this:

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '\\ntsrv1\tohna\SecurityTeam\Varonis\Varonis_monitoring_report\Varonis_Action_Report.csv'

and it doesn't go to the except part where i need to get the mail with the error ,it just stops

anyone know why?

TNX

Comment: Why would `ValueError` catch `IOError`? You're _selectively_ only trying to handle the former, the latter should still raise an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe use `except IOError as e:` or simply `except:` to make sure it catches the error

Answer (score 0):

```
except ValueError as e:
    print("ValueError caught: " + str(e))
```

Just catches exceptions of type `ValueError`.  Exceptions tend to be derived from the `Exception` class, so this would catch any normal exception:

```
except Exception as e:
    print("Exception caught:" + str(e))
```

To be entirely sure you're catching everything, you can use:

```
except:
    print("Unknown exception caught")
```